# environmental variable not available for next command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, environment-variables

We have a shell script named source.sh that exports many ENV variables required for a build.

I am trying to access those ENV variables by running source.sh in my script, but even after running that I am not able to access ENV variables for the succeeding commands.

My Script look alike:

```
#!/bin/bash

sh source.sh
cd $ROOT_VOS
make
```

But here cd $ROOT_VOSis not happening

Comment: As an aside, there's no good reason to be making this an environment variable vs a regular shell variable -- and POSIX conventions specify the namespace of all-uppercase variable names to be used for variables with meaning for the operating system and shell, with lowercase names reserved for application use. (Formally, that's specified for environment variables, but setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so the convention necessarily applies in both places).

Answer (score 3):

`sh source.sh`

...runs `source.sh` in a separate copy of `sh` (actually, since your parent shell is `bash` and the child is `sh`, it's not just a "separate copy", it's an entirely different interpreter). When that separate interpreter exits, local variables and other changes to process-local state are gone. (Environment variables are inherited by *child processes*; they aren't propagated up the tree to parents).

---

Instead, use:

```
# POSIX-compliant: execute every command in source.sh in the current shell
. source.sh
```

...or...

```
# bash-specific, perhaps more-readable, synonym for the same
source source.sh
```